# CodenameOne Error while trying to read theme property

Tags: java, codenameone

When I try to load just a simpel Codename1 Hello World tutorial app I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error while trying to read theme property: 
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.loadTheme(Resources.java:1475)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFileImpl(Resources.java:303)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFile(Resources.java:269)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:189)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:740)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:702)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:666)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.initFirstTheme(UIManager.java:1564)
    at dk.cp3.appname.MyApplication.init(MyApplication.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:117)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1152)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:969)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

I have looked at the net and found some people having the same error but relate it to NetBeans. I use Eclipse 4.7.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: So, you are doing something and that fails. And you read something, and that didn't help. That is in essence what your question is about. How exactly do you expect us to help with such input? You are like a guy calling his garage on the phone telling them "my car is making strange noises. now tell me how to fix that" ... sorry, but that will not work out.

Comment: I've been debuging a bit in the com.codename1.ui.util.Resource class. And the exception is being throwm because of a (resource) key being an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project, select Codename One -> Codename One Settings -> Basic -> Update Client Libs.

This should update the locally installed libraries to the latest which should work correctly with the current theme. Make sure your plugin is up to date too although this shouldn't impact that exception.