# codename1 NullPointerException after update

Tags: java, codenameone

After a project settings update I get this NullPointerException
[EDT] 0:0:0,0 - Codename One revisions: e5578786e9d343acce705b819a37288d29591b72

[EDT] 0:0:0,71 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.ui.SideMenuBar$CommandWrapper.actionPerformed(SideMenuBar.java:1788)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:491)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:533)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:637)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2807)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:4016)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2032)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1028)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:946)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

It seem to bo something within codenameone.
Anybody know how to deal with it?

EDIT.

OK @Shai I think I found why you can't reproduce the exception. I've installed the new plugin v3.8. The examble template called "Forms Navigation" now produce completely different code than it did before. So I think you are testing on this new code, witch allso on my mashine works fine, but i've build my project on top of the former examble code (see it below). So if I am correct, will you please try and test this former code and see if you get the same exception.

```
package dk.cp3.anchorsafe;

import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.CheckBox;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.ui.Command;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.FontImage;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.NavigationCommand;
import com.codename1.ui.RadioButton;
import com.codename1.ui.Slider;
import com.codename1.ui.TextField;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class AnchorSafely {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    private Form home;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }

        //create and build the home Form
        home = new Form("Home");
        home.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        home.addComponent(new Label("This is a Label"));
        home.addComponent(new Button("This is a Button"));
        TextField txt = new TextField();
        txt.setHint("This is a TextField");
        home.addComponent(txt);
        home.addComponent(new CheckBox("This is a CheckBox"));
        RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("This is a Radio Button 1");
        rb1.setGroup("group");
        home.addComponent(rb1);
        RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("This is a Radio Button 2");
        rb2.setGroup("group");
        home.addComponent(rb2);
        final Slider s = new Slider();
        s.setText("50%");
        s.setProgress(50);
        s.setEditable(true);
        s.setRenderPercentageOnTop(true);
        home.addComponent(s);

        Button b1 = new Button("Show a Dialog");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Dialog.show("Dialog Title", "Dialog Body", "Ok", "Cancel");
            }
        });
        home.addComponent(b1);

        //Create Form1 and Form2 and set a Back Command to navigate back to the home Form        
        Form form1 = new Form("Form1");
        setBackCommand(form1);
        Form form2 = new Form("Form2");
        setBackCommand(form2);

        //Add navigation commands to the home Form
        NavigationCommand homeCommand = new NavigationCommand("Home");
        homeCommand.setNextForm(home);
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(homeCommand);

        NavigationCommand cmd1 = new NavigationCommand("Form1");
        cmd1.setNextForm(form1);
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(cmd1);

        NavigationCommand cmd2 = new NavigationCommand("Form2");
        cmd2.setNextForm(form2);
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(cmd2);

        //Add Edit, Add and Delete Commands to the home Form context Menu
        Image im = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_MODE_EDIT, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Command"));
        Command edit = new Command("Edit", im) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Editing");
            }
        };
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu(edit);

        im = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_LIBRARY_ADD, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Command"));
        Command add = new Command("Add", im) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Adding");
            }
        };
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu(add);

        im = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_DELETE, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Command"));
        Command delete = new Command("Delete", im) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Deleting");
            }

        };
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu(delete);

        home.show();
    }

    protected void setBackCommand(Form f) {
        Command back = new Command("") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                home.showBack();
            }

        };
        Image img = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_BACK, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand"));
        back.setIcon(img);
        f.getToolbar().addCommandToLeftBar(back);
        f.getToolbar().setTitleCentered(true);
        f.setBackCommand(back);
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: It's probably one of the parameters/settings given previously to the API. You can see from the [source code](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/SideMenuBar.java) that either `rightPanel` is null or `rightPanel.getStyle()` returns null. Trace backwards from there.

Comment: Can you please provide additional details? Are you using the `Toolbar` or the old `SideMenuBar`? Did you set the command behavior to something? Any other theme constants or settings?

Comment: I simply just tried the provided 'Forms navigation' project. Before updating, it worked fine but after it crashed with the nullpointer exception.
It looks as it uses the Toolbar. I have'nt changed any thems or behaviors.
After the first crash I removed the project and tried it again with same result.

Comment: I just did this and and I don't see any exceptions. Did you update the client libs after the weekend? We released an update with a fix this Sunday?

Comment: Yes i did it yesterday.

Comment: The problem occur when I try to use the side menu to go to a new form.

Comment: I've tried to reinstall every thing and I still get the same exception. I've tested with all skins and it's the same result.
PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: It's the "rightPanel.getStyle()" call that retturn a null.
So in your last lib update there must have been edited some code about that.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, I can't just avoid updating and carry on, cause then i run into this exception instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909312/codenameone-error-while-trying-to-read-theme-property

Comment: Maybe a version of your libs somehow got pulled from an out of date cache. Open your `codenameone_settings.properties` and look at the `libVersion`. Anything above 191 should be good. If it's below you should do an update. We are just publishing 193 so if 192 doesn't work make sure to update again.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I updated to version 193 but it's still the same.

Comment: Updated with update client libs not by changing the value manually? Just to be 100% clear don't change the value manually... FYI our new version of the eclipse plugin released today should no longer require the update client libs for the theme issue

Comment: Well, I may not be the smartest guy, but i'm not completely stupid. I would have expected a more serius investigation of the problem by now. @Shai

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to imply that. This is a problem that did occur to some developers and it was fixed in an update I'm trying to understand why that update didn't get to you and don't really understand how something like that would happen. I tried to reproduce your problem with the form navigation app and it works fine for me with 192 so I need to understand how your system differs from mine and from other users? Currently the question only includes a stack trace which was fixed by now.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog could you please take a look at the EDIT part of my post.

Comment: No I tested on the former code and this didn't happen. Can you maybe post a video of what you are doing? Maybe you are clicking somewhere in some way that is different to what I'm doing?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, here's the video. http://www.3cp.dk/Medier3.mp4

Comment: I'm sorry I have to stop using codename one. My boss' order . Sorry!

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Hopefully he'll reconsider. The good news is that I found the issue

Answer (score 0):

When I saw the video I noticed you used the business theme which I didn't think would be the reason for the problem but it is. The business theme defines the deprecated `commandBehavior` theme constant which you can just remove to solve this.

Comment: This is fixed in this commit https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/2c7ad31b9542dd8bbff2ab00c5a4b0728efa9d0c